# SQL server identity or a self calculated sequence

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design

I am designing a database. I want to define a automatic sequence  on a table primary key field. what is the best solution for it?

I know I can enable identity property for a field, but  it has some problems ( for example its seed jumps on restart and unsuccessful events)

I also can use some calculated sequences. for example I can calculate max of the filed values and after incrementing use it as key for new inserted record.

which one is better? Is there another solution?

Comment: It depends on your actual requirements.

Answer (score 3):

To my mind there's 3 options:

1. Identity - the simplest, but can have gaps when server is restarted etc.
2. Sequence - separate object, you will have still gaps in case of rollback
3. A separate table for the numbers - you won't have gaps, but it can be a hotspot that can cause blocking.

Comment: nice succinct answer.

Comment: Sequence was only introduced in Sql server 2012, so it might not be an option to the OP. Rolling his own sequence / identity is prone to inefficiency and / or uniqueness problems (i.e select max(IdCol) + 1...) I would say that using an Identity and just live with the possible gaps is the best solution. If a no gaps unique ascending order numbers column is required, I would go with a persist calculated column. Good answer, though.